# Struct member cannot be resolved in c

Tags: c, data-structures

I have an header file in c which in it I declare:

```
struct Symbles{
    char symbolName[MAX_LENGTH_SYMBOL];
    int value;
    struct inSymbles *symbolAddress;
    int binaryValue;
    int isData; /*1 is true 0 is false*/
    int isString; /*1 is true 0 is false*/
};
```

With this declartion I use a source file:

```
void start(char *line){
char *ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_CHARS);
char *toCheck=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_CHARS);
char *temp=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_CHARS);
struct Symbles symbles_arr[MAX_LENGTH_SYMBOL];
/*copy the original string to work with a pointer*/
strcpy(ptr,line);
toCheck=strtok(ptr,":");
/*temp will help to check if there is a string or a data sentence*/
strcpy(temp,ptr);
while(toCheck!=NULL)
{
    if(isSymbol(toCheck)) {
        if(!(isEntryExtern(temp,ptr))){
            /*add to symbol list*/
            symbolFlag=TRUE;
            /*symbolTable[symbol_counter]=malloc(sizeof(struct Symbles));*/
            symbles_arr[symbol_counter]=malloc(sizeof(struct Symbles));
            strcpy(symbles_arr[symbol_counter].symbolName,*toCheck);
            /**Symbles.symbolTable[symbol_counter].*symbolName=*toCheck;*/
            }
        else{
            printf("error, symbol and entry or extern");

            return;
            }
        }
}
```

}

The point of this code is to find if a symbol exist in an assembly file, but it's not that important, just this thing with the structs is irritating me.
I have included the header file at the top of the source file, so that won't be the error origin.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are using `typedef` twice. Doesn't that bother you? As an aside - is your function called `isSybmol` or `isSymbol`? Be careful of spelling...

Comment: It does, thank you. But is that the source of the problem? I will fix it now. fix both now.

Comment: What is the error?  Compiler error or what and what are the messages or error behavior?

Comment: it is a compiler error - he doesn't seem to find the member.

Comment: You didn't fix it the right way... your second `typedef` (the one you left in) was the one that needed removing so you actually would be declaring an array.

Comment: Also check your char array copying. its wrong. use memcpy, if its string strcpy etc

Comment: ??? Throughout your entire code you are properly using `strcpy` to copy strings. But on that line you are suddenly trying to assign one array to another. How is that possible? Arrays in C are not assignable. Your line makes no sense at all. If you know how to use `strcpy`, why aren't you using it on that line?

Comment: Thank you fellas, I have fixed now my code. Please check original message @AndreyT

Comment: OK. Now you should probably take a look at the answers given, and see whether any of them deserve either an upvote ("useful") or an accept ("this solved my problem").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two (or more) problems. The first: you are using `typedef` when you are trying to declare an array of structs.  Don't. Instead of

```
typedef struct Symbles symbles_arr[MAX_SYMBOLS_ENTRIES_EXTERNALS];
```

use

```
struct Symbles symbles_arr[MAX_SYMBOLS_ENTRIES_EXTERNALS];
```

Notice that you now have the structure (not a pointer to the structure) - so when you want to access an element you need `.` not `->`  Thus:

```
 symbles_arr[symbol_counter]->symbolName=*toCheck;
```

needs to become

```
 strcpy(symbles_arr[symbol_counter].symbolName, *toCheck);
```

because you allocated space for the symbol name in the structure, and you can't just take that pointer and point it somewhere else.

Finally - you don't need to `malloc` space for `toCheck` since `strtok` actually returns a pointer to the original string (it doesn't make a copy). The side effect of this is that your input string (the one passed to `strtok`) becomes mangled in the process - after you're done using it, it has a lot of `'\0'` added.

There may be other problems, but this should get you on your way...

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

```
typedef struct Symbles symbles_arr[MAX_SYMBOLS_ENTRIES_EXTERNALS];
```

doesn't declare a variable; instead, it creates a `typedef` where `symbles_arr` refers to `struct Symbles[MAX_SYMBOLS_ENTRIES_EXTERNALS]`. Therefore, writing

```
symbles_arr[symbol_counter]->symbolName=*toCheck;
```

would be like writing

```
(struct Symbles[MAX_SYMBOLS_ENTRIES_EXTERNALS])[symbol_counter]->symbolName = *toCheck;
```

This isn't meaningful because you're trying to access a specific array index of a type, which isn't permitted.

To fix this, either drop the `typedef`, making `symbles_arr` an actual array, or create an object of type `Symbles`.

Hope this helps!